# How to implement Auto-fill behavior for search in custom Web Part in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sql-server, sharepoint-list, custom-web-parts

I am trying to implement Auto-fill behavior for search in custom Web Part in SharePoint here I have to read data either from SharePoint list or SQL Server database table.
Here I can implement these both approaches individually which is not what I want,
I want to implement these both approaches together.
Is there any solution out there for such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished it through ajax-call functionality,
which I have implemented through application page.
here is my HTML

```
<div>
<label  for="txtSearch">Search</label>
<input placeholder="Search" class="form-text searchbox" type="text" id="txtSearch" maxlength="255" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

here is my js code for ajax call

```
function SearchText() {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/_layouts/15/searchText/applicationpage.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'searchText':'" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and the server site code template would be as like below

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string searchText)
        {

            if (SQL Table)
            {
                -----------------------------
                ----------------------------
                  ------------------------
            }
            else if (Sharepoint List)
            {
               -----------------------------
                ----------------------------
                ------------------------
            }
            return result;
        }
```